# Accessing json in javascript and displaying it in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I can't figure out why this isn't displaying in my HTML.

I've followed the following examples...

https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

[How to access JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365194/how-to-access-json-in-javascript)

[Accessing Json in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893494/accessing-json-in-javascript)

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

This is what I've got going, currently:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var json = { "year" : "2016",
        "months"  : [ {"July"}, {"August"}, {"September"} ],
        "days" : [ {02}, {03}, {14}, {18}, {10}, {19} ],
        "event" : [ {"Fitness assessment"}, {"Pathology-Uric Acid"}, {"Consultation-General and angiogram"}, {"Medication-Asperlone"}, {"Medication-Celestamine"}, {"Fitness assessment"} ] 
    };

    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = obj.months[0];
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = obj.days[0];
    document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = obj.event[0];
    document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = obj.days[1];
    document.getElementById("event2").innerHTML = obj.event[1];
    document.getElementById("month2").innerHTML = obj.months[1];
    document.getElementById("day3").innerHTML = obj.days[2];
    document.getElementById("event3").innerHTML = obj.event[2];
    document.getElementById("day4").innerHTML = obj.days[3];
    document.getElementById("event4").innerHTML = obj.event[3];
    document.getElementById("day5").innerHTML = obj.days[4];
    document.getElementById("event5").innerHTML = obj.event[4];
    document.getElementById("month3").innerHTML = obj.months[2];
    document.getElementById("day6").innerHTML = obj.days[5];
    document.getElementById("event6").innerHTML = obj.event[5];
};
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="row liketablerow">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h4 id="day"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="images/icon-fitness.png" class="fitness" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <p id="event"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All helpful comments are helpful, thank you.

Comment: I cant see any element in your HTML snippet which you are trying to access and set value to. Do you have those elements in your html ?

Comment: The innerHTML of the h4 tag and the p tag

Comment: You also need to get rid of the {'s around the values inside the arrays. The { and } are used to indicate an object, which must have a key and value like {color: 'red'}. If you only have 1 value in there you will get errors. If you try running this in the console you will see the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json object is not valid, you are using curly brackets for strings in your arrays which is not the correct way to do it using the [json notation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp), here is how it should be :

```
var json = {
  "year" : "2016",
  "months": ["July", "August", "September"],
  "days": [02, 03, 14, 18, 10, 19],
  "event": ["Fitness assessment", "Pathology-Uric Acid", "Consultation-General and angiogram", "Medication-Asperlone", "Medication-Celestamine", "Fitness assessment" ]};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "JSON" isn't actually JSON. It's a JavaScript object. As such, `JSON.parse` won't do anything to it (except break). It's already in the format you need.

```
        var obj = { "year" : "2016",
         "months"  : [ {"July"}, {"August"}, {"September"} ],
         "days" : [ {02}, {03}, {14}, {18}, {10}, {19} ],
         "event" : [ {"Fitness assessment"}, {"Pathology-Uric Acid"}, {"Consultation-General and angiogram"}, {"Medication-Asperlone"}, {"Medication-Celestamine"}, {"Fitness assessment"} ] };
```

^^ change to `obj`

See here for the different between JSON and a JS object literal:

- [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)
- http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 0):

The javascript object notation seems to be wrong. Your events JS object syntax should be below instead :

```
var json = { "year" : "2016",
        "months"  : [ "July", "August", "September" ],
        "days" : [ 02, 03, 14, 18, 10, 19 ],
        "event" : [ "Fitness assessment", "Pathology-Uric Acid", "Consultation-General and angiogram", "Medication-Asperlone", "Medication-Celestamine", "Fitness assessment" ] 
    };
```